# Inserting single delimeter with spacemacs / smartparens

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm editing clojure in spacemacs, and I want to insert an escaped quote mark inside of a string, like this

```
" \" "
```

But when I have this in spacemacs, where `c` indicates where my cursor is

```
" \c "
```

and type `"`, it produces

```
" \"\" "
```

I have no idea why it does that. It would also be nice to know in the general case, how to insert a single delimeter like `(` incase it's necessary without smartparens auto-pairing it and then having to delete a character.

Comment: you can always insert a raw character with `C-q` (`quoted-insert`).  It does that cause there is a smartparens pair defined (assuming you're using smartparens). If you want to disable that pairing for smartparens, add a `(sp-local-pair '(mode-to-disable) "\"" nil :actions nil)` in your clojure hook